# Switching tabs not working on click of tabs with PagerSlidingTabStrips

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, pagerslidingtabstrip

I've integrated `PagerSlidingTabStrips` in my application which runs as expected on Swipe of tabs.

*But selecting tabs on `PagerSlidingTabStrips` doesn't switch  to that fragment which works perfectly on swiping between tabs.*

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
ViewPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fm);
mPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);
pagerSlidingTabStrp = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_sliding_tab_strip);
pagerSlidingTabStrp.setShouldExpand(true);
pagerSlidingTabStrp.setViewPager(mPager);
pagerSlidingTabStrp.setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPagerListener);     


// Capture ViewPager page swipes
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ViewPagerListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                setMotherActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.str_all_contacts_fragment));
                break;
            case 1:
                setMotherActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.str_group_contacts_fragment));
                break;
            case 2:
                setMotherActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.str_call_logs_fragment));
                break;                  
            }
        }
    };
```

*ViewPagerAdapter*

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconTabProvider {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private final int[] ICONS = { R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_contact_selector, R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_friends_selector, 
        R.drawable.tab_icon_zname_call_log_selector };

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int item) {
    switch (item) {

    case 0:
        ContactsFragment homeFragment = new ContactsFragment();
        return homeFragment;
    case 1:
        GroupsFragment groupsFragment = new GroupsFragment();
        return groupsFragment;
    case 2:
        CallLogsFragment callLogsFragment = new CallLogsFragment();
        return callLogsFragment;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
    return ICONS[position];
 }

}
```

*How to make selecting tabs works with `PagerSlidingTabStrips`? Morever `PagerSlidingTabStrips` tabs are not even clickabe.*

*Did I missed out to implement something? Or to add pagerSlidingTabStrips.setClickable(true)? or something?*

Again the selector of `PagerSlidingTabStrips` tabs not selected proper drawable with selector. What could be possible the reason for that?

Here's a picture of it.
[image: PagerSlidingTabStrips]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found out why clicking tab was not working with `PagerSlidingTabStrips` after I've looked out for other options with sliding tabs functionality like `SlidingTabsLayout` which also was not able to click tabs.

Found out problem was with my `xml` layout which covers whole as `ViewPager` which doesn't make tabs clickable of either`PagerSlidingTabStrips` or `SlidingTabsLayout` works.

```
        <com.netdoers.zname.utils.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_sliding_tab_strip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:pstsDividerColor="#FFFFA500"
            app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FFFFA500"
            app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="14dip"
            app:pstsUnderlineColor="#FFFFA500" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />
```

Leaving same height in `Viewpager` as of `PagerSlidingTabStips` from top where `PagerSlidingTabStrips` rendered solved my issue.

Comment: using a LinearLayout is probably better instead of adding margins

Comment: It helped me! If you are using a relative layout Just add   android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" in your viewpager

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the issue is in XML. The issue probably due to RelativeLayout is used om the XML. Consider using LinearLayout will ensure there's no overlap between views.